# How to secure my GCP Windows instance connection with HTTPS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, https, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have my VM machine with google cloud. 
I have hosted ASP.NET application with it.
I have purchased certificate from GoDaddy.
I want to secure my ASP.NET web application secure with Https I did searched on internet I come across this broken link https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates-concepts
I am now in dilemma need rescue.

Comment: I guess I found the answer to this in partial way because when followed This can be done with following two links https://helpdesk.ssls.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001608812-How-to-generate-a-CSR-on-Google-Cloud-platform firstly to generate CSR and put this in certificate to download certificate.

now once certificate authority issued certificate archive then follow steps mentioned in https://helpdesk.ssls.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001602911-How-to-install-a-SSL-certificate-on-Google-Cloud-Platform Hope this will help you ... I am now with new error google says "Private kay is not valid" :-(

Comment: Hi, I think the guide you are looking for is moved to https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates

Comment: To add visibility and help the community please consider posting an answer.

Comment: It was regarding installing ssl certificates with windows instance created GCP.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way do it after lot of googling I will recommend who ever be coming across to see series of video by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMJaYlNgGu0 there are five parts of this tutorial which will give complete guideline to person who is seeking for securing web application virtual windows server create with google compute engine.
Furthermore “it’s all about installing ssl certificates to web server” after you download it from ssl certificates provider like godaddy